# Injecting Google Analytics dynamically

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to inject Google Analytics on acceptance of cookies due to GDPR. I've embedded most of the GA code in a function `enableGoogleAnalytics()` as seen below.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
    function enableGoogleAnalytics() {
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)};
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
    }
</script>
```

Should I be injecting the first line dynamically (shown below) as well? If so, is there are a straightforward way?

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-X"></script>
```

Thanks,